# Intersection of 3 circles with lat long center and meter radius

Tags: javascript, math, formula

I have a question related to the intersection of circle.
I've spent some time on Google already but none of the solution seems to work for now.

I need to get the intersection of three circle. Each of them has a center given in latitude and longitude, and their radius in Meter.

I tried to follow this post [Find intersecting point of three circles programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723641/find-intersecting-point-of-three-circles-programmatically) and translate the code to javascript :

```js
function calculateThreeCircleIntersection(x0, y0, r0,
                                        x1, y1, r1,
                                        x2, y2, r2){

    var a, horizontal_d_1_2_circle, horizontal_d_1_2_circle, distance_1_2_circle, h, rx, ry;
    const EPSILON = 0.0000001;

    horizontal_d_1_2_circle = x1 - x0;
    vertical_d_1_2_circle = y1 - y0;

    distance_1_2_circle = Math.sqrt((vertical_d_1_2_circle*vertical_d_1_2_circle) + (horizontal_d_1_2_circle*horizontal_d_1_2_circle));

    if (distance_1_2_circle > (r0 + r1))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (distance_1_2_circle < Math.abs(r0 - r1))
    {
        return false;
    }


    a = ((r0*r0) - (r1*r1) + (distance_1_2_circle*distance_1_2_circle)) / (2.0 * distance_1_2_circle) ;

    point2_x = x0 + (horizontal_d_1_2_circle * a/distance_1_2_circle);
    point2_y = y0 + (vertical_d_1_2_circle * a/distance_1_2_circle);

    h = Math.sqrt((r0*r0) - (a*a));

    rx = -vertical_d_1_2_circle * (h/distance_1_2_circle);
    ry = horizontal_d_1_2_circle * (h/distance_1_2_circle);

    intersectionPoint1_x = point2_x + rx;
    intersectionPoint2_x = point2_x - rx;
    intersectionPoint1_y = point2_y + ry;
    intersectionPoint2_y = point2_y - ry;

    console.log("INTERSECTION Circle1 AND Circle2:", "(" + intersectionPoint1_x + "," + intersectionPoint1_y + ")" + " AND (" + intersectionPoint2_x + "," + intersectionPoint2_y + ")");

    horizontal_d_1_2_circle = intersectionPoint1_x - x2;
    vertical_d_1_2_circle = intersectionPoint1_y - y2;
    d1 = Math.sqrt((vertical_d_1_2_circle*vertical_d_1_2_circle) + (horizontal_d_1_2_circle*horizontal_d_1_2_circle));

    horizontal_d_1_2_circle = intersectionPoint2_x - x2;
    vertical_d_1_2_circle = intersectionPoint2_y - y2;
    d2 = Math.sqrt((vertical_d_1_2_circle*vertical_d_1_2_circle) + (horizontal_d_1_2_circle*horizontal_d_1_2_circle));

    if(Math.abs(d1 - r2) < EPSILON) {
        console.log("INTERSECTION Circle1 AND Circle2 AND Circle3:", "(" + intersectionPoint1_x + "," + intersectionPoint1_y + ")");
    }
    else if(Math.abs(d2 - r2) < EPSILON) {
        console.log("INTERSECTION Circle1 AND Circle2 AND Circle3:", "(" + intersectionPoint2_x + "," + intersectionPoint2_y + ")"); //here was an error
    }
    else {
        console.log("INTERSECTION Circle1 AND Circle2 AND Circle3:", "NONE");
    }
    return true;
}
```

I tried with some dummy value and it worked

But in my case, the center of the circles are in Lat/Lng, which this code doesn't support, so i tried to convert Lat/Lng to Cartesian Coordinate following this post [Converting from longitude\latitude to Cartesian coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates).

```js
function get_cartesian(lat,lon){
    const earthRadius = 6367000;

    lat = lat * (Math.PI/180);
    lon = lon * (Math.PI/180);

    var x = earthRadius * Math.cos(lat)*Math.cos(lon);
    var y = earthRadius * Math.cos(lat)*Math.sin(lon);

    return [x, y];
}
```

However, when I try to combine the two codes with data that should contains intersecting circles, calculateThreeCircleIntersection return false

```js
calculateThreeCircleIntersection(get_cartesian(50, 4.5)[0],get_cartesian(50, 4.5)[1] , 1000,
                                 get_cartesian(50, 4.501)[0],get_cartesian(50, 4.501)[0] , 1000,
                                 get_cartesian(50.001, 4.501)[0],get_cartesian(50.001, 4.501)[1] , 1000)
```

It should however return intersections since I tested the values on google map.
I know it is a problem with the conversion from Lat/Lng to cartesian, but since I've tested 4 or 5 different way to do the conversion, i'm out of idea.

Does anyone have an idea what should I do ?

To be precise i think i have to find yet another way to convert Lat/Lng to cartesian coordinate, but because i don't even know what they should look like i'm completely lost

Comment: I think you should read [ask] and add your code to the question so that we can see what's wrong.

Comment: @InSync I tried to change my post as best as I could, don't hesitate to point out what's wrong or what's missing with it specifically as it is my first time posting on stackOverflow

Comment: because the 3 circles do not intersect with your calculation.... it exits out on the first if statement. Add a debugger statement and walk through the code and inspect your variables.

Comment: @epascarello I see that it is a problem with the conversion from Lat/Lng, but i don't find a code that work for my situation, the circles given in the function should intersect as i checked it on google map